# Parsing files in subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to parse through all text files which are in different subfolders. The main folder is 'Data'. Inside this, there are many subfolders. I have to parse through all the files inside these subfolders and do some operations. I came across a code but it is not really working.

```
import glob
import os

dir="D:\\College\\Data"
file_write_in_results = open("D:\\result\\test_all_files.txt","w", encoding="utf8") # file in which we will write the desired results
subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]                                                                            
for subdir in subdirs:                                                                                            
    files = next(os.walk(subdir))[2]                                                                            
    if (len(files) > 0):
        for filename in files:            
        #for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
            with open(filename,  encoding="utf8") as f:
                for line in f:
                    if "signed by" in line:
                         file_write_in_results.write(filename)
                         file_write_in_results.write('\n')
file_write_in_results.close()
```

Comment: https://kite.com/python/examples/4195/os-traverse-all-subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate through dirs as they will also be supplied in `root` variable only the `files` needs to be looped in an inner loop like so:

```
import os

dir="D:\\College\\Data"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf8",mode="r") as f:
            pass
            #your file parsing logic goes here
```

Be sure to use the correct `encoding` and `mode`. `mode='rb'` would be safer also you could wrap it all in a `try  except` to handle files that are problematic so the parsing process would not stop if it would encounter such files.